# Problem with channel rack reproducing notes from Pattern which shouldnt be there

Tags: fl-studio

I'm using FL Studio 20, I have the following problem.

I have 3 patterns, the first has notes in Instrument #1, the second has notes in Instrument #1 and #2 and the third has notes in Instrument #1, #2 and #3. I have the patterns placed sequentially in the Playlist. When they reproduce for the first time, everything is ok, but when they start reproducing again, Pattern 1 which has only notes in Instrument #1, reproduces notes from Instrument #1 and #2.

The same problem appears if I place Pattern 1 again at the end of the Playlist, when it reproduces Pattern 1, Pattern 2 and Pattern 3 everything is ok, but when it goes to reproduce Pattern 1 again at the end of the Playlist, Instrument #1 and Instrument #2 are reproduced, when Pattern 1 has only notes for Instrument 1.

Is this a bug or something, or a missconception of how the whole Playlist-Pattern-Channel Rack works from my part?